# How do I wire a three way switch with two lights?

Tags: electrical

My "power in"  box has its black/white and ground and also the three wire cable( black /white /red and ground)  and also the first light wires ( black/white).    how do I wire this.

It is going to two lights--  the first light is pretty simple - just black and white-- ends at fixture--- also the cable feeding light # 2
 and then moving on to the second three way box.
It seems I have an extra black wire in the initial "power in" box...

Do I hook the black power in with the black cable and let the current circulate?
  or attach the power in to the dark screw.  and then what do I do with the other two black wires? black cable to black first light?    white cable to single light screw side,( as traveler) and red to double screw light screw side?

I have seen a couple photos and nothing is crystal clear.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my understanding of what you have described, I believe you are dealing with a dead-end 3-way switch setup with what is known as an extended switch leg. **Translation:** *all junctions are made in the first 3-way switch box*.

Your questions/guesses on how to wire it are not exactly clear. I recommend following this wiring diagram. Please clarify if this wiring diagram does not apply to what you have described.

### Wiring Diagram

[image]

### Circuit Example

[image]

Comment: well I have way more wires than that diagram--  the first box basically has three black three white a red and 3 grounds....

Comment: @dina the provided diagram & photo show 3 blacks, 3 whites, and a red in the first box. Grounds are implied.

Comment: This setup *may* violate 404.2(C), depending on where the switches are located, and which code version you're following.

Comment: Yeah, you'd need to use /4 wire to wire up the loop under the 2014 (i.e. current) NEC, with a "dead end" neutral being provided all the way out to the furthest switch.